# How can we subscribe to security advisories / bulletins about Azure DevOps Services?

Tags: security, azure-devops

We would like to subscribe to security advisories / bulletins / issue notifications about Azure DevOps Services impacting our organization. Specifically, would like to receive such notifications via an email distribution list (DL). How can we do that?

I've found a guide about such bulletings / advisories for Azure in general: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/stay-informed-security. Would it be correct to assume that these cover Azure DevOps Services as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions for your reference.

1. You can [create service health alerts in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/alerts-activity-log-service-notifications-portal#create-a-service-health-alert-using-the-azure-portal). When you create an alert, select the services shown as below.

[image]

2. Subscribe to [the RSS feed](https://status.dev.azure.com/_rss) to receive updates in your feed reader.
3. The Azure Resource health REST API can retrieve the current health status of each of the Azure DevOps Services. You can use it to build an automated solution to monitor the infrastructure incidents. See more info from [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/service-status-info?view=azure-devops).